# MAE of each class image folder in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have 19 folders with specific ages, am running a regression on this in keras. Could anyone please help with how to calculate the MAE of individual folders instead of the overall MAE?

In case of multi-class following code gives the accuracy of individual classes, I need something like this for MAE.

```
 def single_class_accuracy(interesting_class_id):

     def acc1(y_true, y_pred):

      class_id_true = K.argmax(y_true)
      class_id_preds = K.argmax(y_pred)
       accuracy_mask = K.cast(K.equal(class_id_preds, interesting_class_id), 'int32')

       class_acc_tensor = K.cast(K.equal(class_id_true, class_id_preds), 'int32') * 
       accuracy_mask
       class_acc = K.cast(K.sum(class_acc_tensor), 'float32') / 
       K.cast(K.maximum(K.sum(accuracy_mask), 1), 'float32')
       return class_acc
    return acc1
```

I need help me writing code to calculate MAE of individual class in Keras.

I have defined MAE as given below, could somebody confirm whether it is correct or not?

```
def single_class_mae(interesting_class_id):
    def mae1(y_true, y_pred):
        class_id_true = K.argmax(y_true, axis=-1)
        class_id_pred = K.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1)
        precision_mask = K.cast(K.equal(class_id_pred, 
        interesting_class_id), 'int32')
        class_prec_tensor = K.cast(K.equal(class_id_true, 
        class_id_pred), 'int32') * precision_mask
        K.cast(K.maximum(K.sum(precision_mask), 1), 'float32')
        a=K.mean(K.abs(precision_mask - 
         class_prec_tensor),axis=-1)  
           
        return a
    mae1.__name__ = 'mae1_1_{}'.format(interesting_class_id)
    return mae1
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have this loss function built in keras library.

```
mae = tf.keras.losses.MeanAbsoluteError()
print(mae(y_true,y_pred))
```

Just run this code in a *for loop* to get the individual MAE for each of the 19 classes you have.

Comment: Thanks but that give overall MAE, I need to calculate MAE of each age group.

Comment: How to create a custom metric for individual class?